# Asus motherboard P5P43TD BIOS doesn't show Intel Virtualization Technology option

Tags: bios, virtualization

My motherboard is an Asus P5P43TD. It has default values loaded, and in the advanced menu in the CPU Configuration section, the Intel Virtualization (VT-x) option is not listed. I have upgraded and downgraded the BIOS from Asus's website.

I have a Core 2 Duo E7200 2.5GHz and I believe this CPU supports the x64 technology for virtualization. I also have 4 GB of DDR3 RAM, but I don't think that matters. My OS is Windows 7 64 bit.

I am trying to install Windows Server 2012 using VMware for an assignment.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately your processor the Core 2 Duo E7200 does not supports Intel's Virtualization Technology (VT-x). You can check it [here](http://ark.intel.com/products/35348/Intel-Core2-Duo-Processor-E7200-3M-Cache-2_53-GHz-1066-MHz-FSB).

As for the chipset of the motherboard that you have mentioned, the P43 Express Chipset does not supports Intel's Virtualization Technology for Directed I/O (VT-d) either. You can confirm it from [here](http://ark.intel.com/products/36525/Intel-82P43-Graphics-and-Memory-Controller-Hub).